# Webfont size and memory issues

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I wanted to know if loading huge webfonts can cause issues on the browser ? 
I have to use a Korean font ( Malgun ) which is 4Mo. And the bold one which is 4 megs too.

I use them on an ipad exclusively for a phonegap project.
Is there a risk of taking a lot of memory ( I mean, 8Mo ) into the browser ?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: I would guess that all the font is loaded into virtual memory, so indeed you are eating 8Mbytes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will affect the browser in that you will have to download the font when you first visit the site. That is a pretty large font file, though. You should consider taking the font into [FontLab](http://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/fontlab-studio/) and truncating it to only the glyphs you need. You may also want to look to see if there is a vector or web version of the font.

If these aren't an option, you could also try asynchronously loading the font. Here is a [great post on CSS tricks](http://css-tricks.com/thinking-async/) about loading things asynchronously. You would simply substitute the JS file in this example with a stylesheet containing your `@font-face` declarations. Note: This method may cause a flash of unstyled text.